# Is $f(x,y,z) = x+2y-3z$ a continuous function? How do I decide without graphing the function?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

I am just starting to learn continuity of functions and trying to find out ways how to figure out if a given function is continuous or not. So far I have found that we will have to graph a function to decide if it is continuous or not. is there any other ways to figure out if $f(x,y,z) = x+2y-3z$ a continuous function?

Comment: Are $y,z$ constants? Or should it be $f(x,y,z)$?

Comment: sorry I have edited. it should be (,,). Thanks

Comment: Actually, you have to know whether a function is continuous or not in order to graph it.

Comment: I’m curious how you’d go about graphing a real-valued function of three variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $f(x,y,z)=x+2y-3z$ is a continuous function. In fact, any function of the form $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$ for constants $a,b$ and $c$ is continuous. There are a number of rules to help you decide if a given function is continuous. For example, the sum or product of two continuous functions is always continuous. A continuous function raised to a continuous function is always continuous.

Consider the functions $g(x,y)=\sin(x)$ and $h(x,y)=\cos y.$ Because they are both continuous, they can be combined by multiplication, addition, and exponentiation to get new continuous functions. So $h(x,y)=(2\sin x\cos y+\cos^4y)^3$ will also be continuous.

Going back to your example, the functions $x,$ $y$, and $z$ are known to be continuous. So, multiplying by constants, $2y$ and $-3z$ must also be continuous. Then adding these terms,
$$
x+2y-3z
$$
must be continuous too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about the functions in quadratic forms such as  2−3+^2 ≤5 ; 4^2−2+^2+4+10^2=100?

Comment: Those equations are not, strictly speaking, functions. But if you want to know if $f(x,y,z)=x^2-3xy+z^2$ and $g(x,y,z)=4x^2-2xy+y^2+4xz+10z^2$ are continuous functions, then the answer is yes, for largely the same reasons I explain in my post.

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you are in first or second year.  For first year, subrosa has a good answer, although you can only raise to a continuous power if the base function is positive.

For second year, suppose $||(x,y,z)-(x_0,y_0,z_0)||\lt\delta$. Then $|f(x,y,z)-f(x_0,y_0,z_0)|=|(x-x_0)+2(y-y_0)-3(z-z_0)| $. Show it is less than some multiple of the distance between the points, so for any $\epsilon$ you can pick a delta to ensure the f values are within epsilon of each other.